# Error when trying to put in my assets files in my AIDE project

Tags: html, webview, project, aide

There's a challenge I ever encountered when it comes to adding HTML load in my AIDE project, so I don't where the challenges are coming from. This is what I did please help me out. I paste this code in the mainActivity.java so that I can be able to input my HTML file.... so do like this still there's error report

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.